# C# Scroll Bar Behavior

Tags: c#, scroll, bitmap, user-controls

I have a user control that uses a vertical scroll bar to browse through an array [0x0000 - 0xffff].  The user control creates a bitmap, of the data, in the background and is refreshed only after the scroll bar is released.  What I have noticed is erratic data, especially if I drag the scroll bar handle (if I just click through the data range it seems to be ok).  I suspect that there is some sort of latency issue going on here but am not sure why.

```
  private void displayArrayData(ushort scrollbar.value)

       {
          //here is where I call the method (on its own thread)
          //that updates the bitmap array
          displayDataMethod = scrollbar.value;
       }
       // transfers bitmap to user control for display
       Refresh();
```

I hope I explained this clearly enough.  Any thoughts?

Comment: You shouldn't call `Refresh` you should call `Invalidate` which then prompts the `Paint` event to fire, which is where you should be drawing your bitmap

Comment: @Matt Tried it but Invalidate goes no where, does nothing.

Comment: Are you drawing your image in the paint event?

Comment: Yes, 'private void MC6800Screen_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)'